# How to split Python logging file by file size

Tags: python, django, logging

I am using Django and have included Python's default logging library. I have following configuration for logging (in settings.py):

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s %(name)s-%(levelname)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s %(funcName)s)]: %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s %(name)s-%(levelname)s]: %(message)s',
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file-django': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename':  os.path.join(PROJECT_LOGS, 'django.log'),
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'file-application': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename':  os.path.join(PROJECT_LOGS, 'application.log'),
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'file-core': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename':  os.path.join(PROJECT_LOGS, 'core.log'),
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['file-django'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'application': {
            'handlers': ['file-application'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'core': {
            'handlers': ['file-core'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

I am trying to split result logging files using only configuration. I "googled" and found few solutions but all of them are code based.

Comment: What's wrong with using a `RotatingFileHandler`?

Comment: I am looking for a solution where I can use configuration.

Comment: And why can't you configure it?

Comment: your request is not clear, are you looking for a some tool to parse the logs? what for? are you looking for a log viewer?

Comment: I am looking for "how to configure python logging to log into file and if file size for example equals to 100MB split it into another file".

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler** in your configuration file **setting.py**, take your handler 'file-django' as example and assume you split it into a new file when its size over than 100MB:

```
'file-django': {
    'level': 'DEBUG',
    'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
    'filename':  os.path.join(PROJECT_LOGS, 'django.log'),
    'maxBytes': 104857600, # 1024*1024*100B (100MB)
    'backupCount': 10, # keep at most 10 log files
    'formatter': 'simple'
},
```

Reference: https://xxx-cook-book.gitbooks.io/django-cook-book/Logs/Handlers/FileHandler/rotating-file-handler.html

Answer (score 1):

Use Ignacio's comment and [look up](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) how to use `RotatingFileHandler`; it splits by file size and you *can* configure it declaratively in Django via the `LOGGING` dictionary.